# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: talend

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, fatal-error, talend

I was trying to run talend open studio for data integration on Ubuntu server(headless) in AWS, while opening talend it’s throwing an error:

> ```
> [INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
> [INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
> [INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
> [INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=3116, tid=0x00007fd3231ed700
> #
> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  0x0000000000000000
> #
> # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
> #
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
> # /home/ra003/Desktop/hs_err_pid3116.log
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> #
> ```

[I have atttached a log file of error here PFA](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjYkn1FS7Pp9iK5JN-Gi5ILTLXsVqw)

I am not able to understand what is the issue. Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: is it a ubuntu desktop on which you are getting this issue? or ubuntu server..?

Comment: @garpitmzn its ubuntu desktop on which i am getting this issue

Comment: i tried on ubuntu server server also, but getting same error there also

Comment: I solved the issue with reinstalling the java in my ubuntu desktop, but still getting error in ubuntu server although I have installed GUI for my server also